What is in the LD2410B human presence sensor
I am trying to search for a schematic for this human presence sensor, see here. However, I cannot find anything.
This is looking like some sort of secret PCB that does not exist online in the individual IC level.
Has anyone been able to figure out what IC they are using? The spec sheet explains the theory of operation but it would be nice to know how it is achieved at a component level as well.

I think a silicon micro-S3KM1110 IC is used. I haven't yet found a S3KM1110 datasheet, but Rd-03Specification is another module which uses the same IC and contains a block diagram of the S3KM1110.

AIThinker use them. They Are reasonably competent and if they use them as long as you're using the source that they are chances are they work OK

@RussellMcMahon the boards are cheap, so it's worth trying this "new" tech out and see how reliable they are.

In the photo it reads S3KM1110 which is a millimeter wave sensor IC.
The component really does everything and the PCB just has the wiring and pad antennas for the chip.

I need a higher resolution screen, I cannot read that much of detail. However thank you.

Most similar modules use the same chip.

Do you know of any equilvalent IC made by a more reputable IC manufaturing, like TI, Infineon, Analogue devices, etc... ?

@JoeyB I don't think TI make devices which operate at 24 GHz, instead the TI devices use the 60GHz and 77GHz frequency bands. See 24 GHz Radar in the TI Radar Academy

@ChesterGillon I see why TI uses it, they have a very sales worthy comparison of why 60GHz is better than 24GHz...

Here is a comparison of various 24GHz modules that lists the chips they are using (looks like 5 different part numbers).

I was able to get brief 1-2 page English-language overviews of the ICL1112 by registering, however the full datasheet is not freely available online without some additional contact. There's an EVK available from their online shop at a reasonable price (CNY ¥798).
